# ASP.net core integration testing with inherited Startup class. Unable to locate View

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I am attempting to write some integration tests against aspnet core 2.2.  I want to use a TestStartup class that inherits from the normal Startup class to configure resources and services for testing purposes.

A simple example (can be found here: https://github.com/davidgouge/aspnet-integration-testing):

I have a solution that contains two projects:

IntegrationTestingWeb (a barebones aspnet mvc app)
IntegrationTestingTests (a testing project)

I have a test that uses the Web Startup class and asserts that OK is returned from `/Home/Privacy`

```
[Test]
public async Task GetPrivacy_Through_Normal_Startup()
{
    var builder = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>();
    var client = new TestServer(builder).CreateClient();
    var result = await client.GetAsync("/Home/Privacy");
    result.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

This test passes.

If I create a TestStartupInTestProject class that inherites from Startup but place it in the Tests project, then I have to do some extra work when creating the WebHostBuilder but then the test fails.

```
[Test]
    public async Task GetPrivacy_Through_Test_Startup_In_Test_Project()
    {
        var builder = new WebHostBuilder().ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            var startupAssembly = typeof(TestStartupInTestProject).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

            var manager = new ApplicationPartManager();
            manager.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(startupAssembly));
            manager.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(typeof(HomeController).Assembly));
            manager.FeatureProviders.Add(new ControllerFeatureProvider());
            manager.FeatureProviders.Add(new ViewComponentFeatureProvider());
            services.AddSingleton(manager);
        }).UseStartup<TestStartupInTestProject>();
        var client = new TestServer(builder).CreateClient();

        var result = await client.GetAsync("/Home/Privacy");

        result.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

The error in the failure is:

```
Tests.Tests.GetPrivacy_Through_Test_Startup_In_Test_Project

System.InvalidOperationException : The view 'Privacy' was not found. The 
following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/Privacy.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Privacy.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Privacy.cshtml
```

So it looks like because my Startup class is located in the Test project, the views cannot be located.  What setting am I missing to be able to find the Views?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was missing `.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\..\\..\\..\\..\\IntegrationTestingWeb")` when creating the WebHostBuilder.  As it sounds, it sets the root dir where the app will look for Views etc.